# How to increase the Cassandra row size above 64KB

Tags: cassandra, bigdata

I read that Apache Cassandra supported  maximum size  of a row is 64KB. But I need to save a record with a size of 560 KB. Is that possible.

Comment: Where did you read that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible if you store data in a column value instead of column key.

In Cassandra, the 64KB limitation is only for column keys, which determine the ordering of data in a partition. For column values, the size limitation [is 2GB](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraLimitations).

[This page](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/ddl/ddl_compound_keys_c.html) describes the difference between clustering columns (aka column keys) and regular columns (aka column values).

Comment: Thank you for feed back ,Still i am  confusing . i have a table with two column ID and description .For example if  ID =1 ,the description column value   is grater than 560 KB.So i am not able to select that specific  raw.

Comment: To be able to store description with size > 560KB, you need to declare it as a not being a part of the primary key definition. E.g. `CREATE TABLE tableName (id int, description text, PRIMARY KEY (id))`.